# Transfer funds to India moving permanently

Tags: united-states, taxes, india, non-resident, money-transfer

I am moving to India permanently in next 2 months from USA.

What are my options to move my funds from USA to India considering I do not have NRE account. i.e. Is it mandatory to have NRE account?

How long can I retain NRI status once I land in India, so that I can transfer funds without any issues.

Comment: First, I recommend that you leave your money in the USA. It's a better and safer place for it. And it's fairly easy to move money from the US to India, as long as you don't want to move it back to the US again. There are a lot of competing services, some of them quite cheap. Just do a search. It wouldn't make sense for me to mention specific services, because I've never used any of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can transfer funds into normal savings account. You can also open resident currency account and transfer the funds into this account.

If you are returning for good, you become RNOR, resident not ordinarily resident Indian immediately for tax purposes. The taxation is same as NRI, income in US is not taxed in India, interest, rental, capital gains, etc. Income in India is taxed.

After 2 years you become Resident Indian and all income (not the savings when you were NRI) rental, interest, capital gains are taxable in India, you can get some relief under DTAA, dual tax avoidance agreement

Comment: Thank you for your response Dheer. As an NRI I am not suppose to have normal saving account and for NRE the banks are asking for valid visa (Visa is required for entry, the legal status in USA are determined by various other documents). I guess only option for me to get resident currency account once I land in India and transfer funds.

Comment: @Prasad if you don't have any account in India, you can open one upon landing.